# Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine not referencing

Tags: .net, ironruby

I am building a .NET project with C# using IronPython 2.6.2 and IronRuby 1.1.3, with reference to the Microsoft.Scripting and Microsoft.Scripting.Core libraries provided by the  IronPython distribution.

However, Visual Studio is complaining about the following error even though I've already referenced the libraries with both 'using' and in 'Project References':

> The type 'Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.1.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1'.

My reference versions are as below:

- IronPython: 2.6.10920.0
- IronRuby: 1.1.3.0
- Microsoft.Scripting & Microsoft.Scripting.Core: 1.0.0.0

Is this a reference version mismatch issue or is there something else I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error, but I was just referencing bad .dll - the Microsoft.Dynamic shows up as Microsoft.Scripting in Add Reference window - just check the full path. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, in the "Reference Manager" search for Microsoft.Scripting and choose the one refers to Microsoft.Scripting.dll

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.This is because of not referencing the scripting dlls or correct dll.In Visual studio->project->reference it shows many dlls with same name alike Microsoft.Scripting. Just put mouse pointer for some time over it and it will show you the complete dll name.If it is exactly Microsoft.Scripting.dll then add it.......Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure this is a problem?

For example: I see similar referential problems with my IronPython project BEFORE I build.  It does successfully build, and it no longer complains after I do so.

It never bothered me enough to figure out why this is happening.  But confirm whether or not you can still build even with those error messages.